# how to free the server cache in java ee programming

Tags: java, database, glassfish

I made a java EE application using EJBs. But when I make changes by hand on the database(directly with de DBMS). It is only taken into account by the application when I redeploy the application. I really do not know why but I suspect a problem of cache. But I do not know how empty the glasfish cache! I'm using glasfish, eclipslink and netbeans.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: First of all, you can call 'flush' after each merge/persist call within Java. You can subsequently close the DB connection (connection with your persistence unit), from within your J2EE application. This will write any cache into your relational database.

Comment: You use Glassfish - which is no longer in development. Its successor is called Payara - I worked with it, and recommend you to upgrade Glassfish to Payara.

Comment: thanks so much for your answer. But when i update my database by the application, there is no probleme and i can see the changes when i redisplay the data. The problem occur when i modify the database directly by the DBMS. so i don't thing the flush can be the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I finished by refreshing my data after recovrying them from DB.It works now.